# Familiar with Regex, however don't understand this basic concept

Tags: regex

**Example 1)**

Simple example, if I wanted to create a regex for integers - a non-empty string of digits.

digit = '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'

integers = digit digit+

According to my notes, **'digit digit+'** will be used. What I don't understand is that why is the **'digit'** there? Is that not redundant?

Can the regex not be just be **'digit+'**? A 1 or more match will match all digits.

**Example 2)**

Extracted from a book

The programming language C adopted the convention of signalling the use of hexadecimal (base-16) numbers by using the prefix “0x”, followed by a non-empty sequence of the digits “0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F” to represent the value of such numbers. This allows for a convenient representation of binary patterns that are multiples of 4 bits long (one
hexadecimal digit for each four-bit group), e.g. OxA01E represents a 16-bit pattern, the “word” size of the machine for which C was originally developed.

Give a regular expression that characterises C’s representation of hexadecimal numbers of arbitrary length, making use of hdigit as defined below.

```
hdigit = (’0’|’1’|’2’|’3’|’4’|’5’|’6’|’7’|’8’|’9’|’A’|’B’|’C’|’D’|’E’|’F’)
```

My answer: 'Ox' hdigit+

Actual answer: 'Ox' hdigit hdigit*

**SOLVED** hidigit+ is synonymous with hdigit hdigit*

What is the explanation in this case?

Comment: You are correct. Any chance there is a typo in your notes?

Comment: Haven't you just tried to test your assumptions?

Comment: I have updated my question to show another example.

Comment: You need at least two characters after `0x` not one. Hence `hdigit hdigit+`.

Comment: @revo Where in the question does it say you need at least two digits after '0x'? I gathered that it can be one digit as the question says 'hexadecimal numbers of arbitrary length'

Comment: Every digit in hex represents 4 bits in binary. You need two to represent a byte. It's C style of representing hex numbers that you probably weren't aware of.

Comment: @revo Right, okay thanks.

Comment: @revo 0x1 is a perfectly valid C hexadecimal literal (as are 0x2, 0x3, ... 0xF). There's nothing in C that requires hex literals to represent a byte of data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2xf226.aspx

Comment: So '0x' hdigit+ can be acceptable regex? @Nick

Comment: Absolutely. I upvoted @coredump comment because I think your answers are correct. Only thing that makes sense to me is that your notes actually say `'0x' hdigit hdigit*` and `digit digit*` but that seems unlikely since they are equivalent to `'0x' hdigit+` and `digit+`, as you wrote.

Comment: Yes, sorry I made a mistake. The actual answer should be 'Ox' hdigit hidigt * @Nick